# bash precedence with compound expression

Tags: bash

I would like to go through a list of files and check whether they exist, giving an error and exiting if a file does not exist. I wrote the following code:

```
FILES=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )

for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
        [ -e "${file}" ] || ( echo "ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2 && exit )
done
```

It runs without error, and yields the following (if none of the files exists):

```
ERROR: file1.txt does not exist
ERROR: file2.txt does not exist
ERROR: file3.txt does not exist
```

Why is "exit" never executed? Additionally, I would like to know the preferred way to do what I'm trying to do (control grouping with the parentheses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be because you run `( echo "ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2 && exit )` as a subprocess (your command is inside () )? So you are exiting from the subprocess.
This is a trace of your shell script (I got it with `set -x`):

```
+ FILES=(file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt)
+ for file in '${FILES[@]}'
+ '[' -e file1.txt ']'
+ echo 'ERROR: file1.txt does not exist'
ERROR: file1.txt does not exist
+ exit
+ for file in '${FILES[@]}'
+ '[' -e file2.txt ']'
+ echo 'ERROR: file2.txt does not exist'
ERROR: file2.txt does not exist
+ exit
+ for file in '${FILES[@]}'
+ '[' -e file3.txt ']'
+ echo 'ERROR: file3.txt does not exist'
ERROR: file3.txt does not exist
+ exit
```

This works:

```
set -x
FILES=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )

for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
        [ -e "${file}" ] || echo "ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2 && exit
done
```

Put `set -x` in your file and see yourself.

Or like this

```
set -x
FILES=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )

for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
        [ -e "${file}" ] || (echo "ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2) && exit
done
```

**Update**
I guess you are asking about [bash - grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

This is grouping and executing in the same process

```
FILES=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )

for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
        [ -e "${file}" ] || { echo "ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2; exit; }
done
```

This is grouping and executing in the subprocess

```
FILES=( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt )

for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
        [ -e "${file}" ] || ( echo "ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2; exit )
done
```

Comment: OK but how do I control grouping? In your example it happens to work out because I guess the default is `&&` has higher precedence than `||` (does it?), but what if I want the first two grouped? That is, I want to evaluate `[ -e "${file}" ] || echo "ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2` AND `exit`. In this example it doesn't make sense but I would like to understand grouping better.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for the lack of clarity. It's hard to ask a good question without knowing the correct terminology. Is there a reason you changed echo `"ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2 && exit` `echo "ERROR: ${file} does not exist" >&2; exit`? Practically I guess it doesn't matter but I'm wondering why you did it. Perhaps it's more secure because if for some reason the echo fails, the program should still exit?

Comment: No, there is no special reason for that.

Comment: You must always make sure to quote `"${FILES[@]}"`. Since the `exit` in the final case occurs within the subshell, it will fail. Also, don't use all-caps variable names for purposes internal to your script.